# rewrite www on the domain and non-www on the subdomain with the same htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have website which works fine and have following in the htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Above gives me all urls with `www` prefix. Now I create version of the site for the mobile phone browsers and want to use `http://m.mydomain.com/` for that version. Both domain and subdomain point to the same folder which is public_html folder. And because of the code in the htaccess file now I have `http://www.m.mydomain.com/` instead of `http://m.mydomain.com/` 
How can I keep www rewrite rule for the domain and get non-www urls for the subdomain in the same htaccess file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the specific case of your `http://m.mydomain.com` you could simply add another condition

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now, the only time `www.` will be appended is if the URL doesn't already start with a `www.` or `m.`. Multiple `RewriteCond` lines are allowed for each `RewriteRule`, and all must pass for the `RewriteRule` to be applied.